# Decoding Particular Element of JSON In PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode JSON

I am reading the JSON through STOMP. There are different JSON datasets so I need to work out which JSON dataset has come through. I do this by reading its title.

However there is one particular dataset I am having trouble reading

```
  foreach (json_decode($msg->body,true) as $event) {
    if(isset($event['schemaLocation'])) {
    $schedule_id=($event['schedule']['schedule_start_date']); 
    $signalling_id=($event['schedule']['schedule_segment']['signalling_id']);

    echo $schedule_id;
    }
```

In the above example the isset function works fine and also $schedule_id obtains the right answer

However the $signalling_id gives an error of **Undefined index:**

Here is a dump of PART of the JSON (Its rather long............).The piece of JSON with the signalling_id is towards the end of the JSON. Any help to get the variable signalling_id much appreciated.

```
    array(7) {
    ["schemaLocation"]=>
    string(72) "http://xml.networkrail.co.uk/ns/2008/Train itm_vstp_cif_messaging_v1.xsd"
    ["classification"]=>
    string(8) "industry"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    string(13) "1410374918000"
    ["owner"]=>
    string(12) "Network Rail"
    ["originMsgId"]=>
    string(47) "2014-09-10T18:48:38-00:00vstp.networkrail.co.uk"
    ["Sender"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["organisation"]=>
      string(12) "Network Rail"
      ["application"]=>
      string(4) "TOPS"
      ["component"]=>
      string(4) "VSTP"
    }
    ["schedule"]=>
    array(11) {
      ["schedule_id"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["transaction_type"]=>
      string(6) "Create"
      ["schedule_start_date"]=>
      string(10) "2014-09-10"
      ["schedule_end_date"]=>
      string(10) "2014-09-10"
      ["schedule_days_runs"]=>
      string(7) "0010000"
      ["applicable_timetable"]=>
      string(1) "N"
      ["CIF_bank_holiday_running"]=>
      string(1) " "
      ["CIF_train_uid"]=>
      string(6) "W64017"
      ["train_status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["CIF_stp_indicator"]=>
      string(1) "O"
      ["schedule_segment"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(20) {
          ["signalling_id"]=>
          string(4) "5Y75"
          ["uic_code"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["atoc_code"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["CIF_train_category"]=>
          string(2) "EE"
          ["CIF_headcode"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["CIF_course_indicator"]=
          ............................................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

schedule_segment is itself an array, so instead of

```
['schedule']['schedule_segment']['signalling_id']);
```

that should probably be

```
['schedule']['schedule_segment'][0]['signalling_id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the var dump, signalling_id is inside another array. Use:

```
$signalling_id=($event ['schedule']['schedule_segment'][0]['signalling_id']);
```

If that one element array with key 0 is not constant throughout, you may need some logic to figure out what it is in each iteration.

Comment: Just testing that now thanks. Waiting for JSON to come through STOMP